# How to use the length of an integer variable as the termination condition in a for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a for loop such as:

```
for (int indexCount = 2, thirdNumber.ToString().Length!=1000; indexCount++)
```

I want the loop to terminate when there are 1000 digits in `thirdNumber`. How can I do this?

Comment: In this case, I prefer a while loop.  The for loop is nice when the same variable (say `i`) is used in the initialization, end condition and increment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to have an int with 1000 digits. The maximum int value is 2,147,483,647, which is only 10 digits. As far as I'm aware, there are no built-in data types that would represent a number with 1000 digits, or even 100 digits for that matter.

**Edit:**
A [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) can hold an arbitrarily large number (thanks [Bradley Uffner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526724/bradley-uffner)). You'll need to add a reference to the System.Numerics assembly. If you use/are using that as your data type, your original comparison of `thirdNumber.ToString()!=1000` would be a valid check to see if it is not 1000 digits.

You could also take a more numbers-based approach and compare the BigInteger being checked to the smallest thousand digit number, which is a 1 followed by 999 zeroes. I'm not sure which method would be faster with numbers of this size, though I'd suspect the comparison between two BigIntegers.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BigInteger minThousandDigits = BigInteger.Parse(new string('9', 999)) + 1;
        BigInteger thousandMoreDigits = BigInteger.Parse(new string('5', 1000));
        BigInteger notAThousandDigits = BigInteger.Parse(new string('9', 999));

        //Displays false
        Console.WriteLine($"Is the first number less than a thousand digits? {thousandMoreDigits < minThousandDigits}");

        //Displays true
        Console.WriteLine($"Is the second number less than a thousand digits? {notAThousandDigits < minThousandDigits}");

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes - I have just run into this problem. I am trying to recreate a program I have made in Python - which seems to work okay.

Comment: How do you know thirdNumber variable is an integer ?

Comment: Well it's probably (hopefully) not a string because it's being ToString()'d. The name of the variable is "number." Even if the data type is decimal, there is still no way to reach 1000 digits.

Comment: [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) can hold that many digits, and it is part of the base framework (since 4.0).

Comment: Neat! Hadn't seen that

Answer (score -1):

Use a do loop:

```
    int indexCount = 2;
    do 
    {
        // Whatever
        indexCount++;
    } while (thirdNumber.ToString().Length != 1000);
```

Note that the loop will always execute at least once in the above example. You can avoid this by using a `break` statement:

```
    int indexCount = 2;
    do 
    {
        if (thirdNumber.ToString().Length == 1000) break;
        // Whatever
        indexCount++;
    } while (true);
```

The above assumes that length will eventually be equal to 1000, otherwise you'll have an infinite loop.